# Handle Theming Issues between Win XP and Win 7 machines in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, themes

My WPF app which is hosted in winform app shows the dersied highlighted color of a selected Xamdatagrid row in Win XP, however when run on Win 7 machine the color changes to lighter shade rendering the highlighted row as unreadable.

Any guidelines to approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are using system defined colors. I'm afraid you have to introduce your own theming:

http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/

Of course you can still use the colors you want by just creating a custom theme.

You can also try to force using specific windows theme:

http://arbel.net/2006/11/03/forcing-wpf-to-use-a-specific-windows-theme/

(Luna is WinXp)

Comment: It would but it's a hack - what if new windows comes out and change some other different color ?

Comment: in That case even the theme would break

Comment: Do as you please Rauld. I hope you will solve your problem in the way that will suit you best!